# Elementor "Sticky Menus" Conflict With Notification Bars "Push Down" Effects

Tags: elementor

We have designed and set a menu and top bar as "sticky" within Elementor's Visual Effects settings, and they work fine.

However whenever we add any kind of 'notification' bar plugin to add a notification at the top of the site, whether we try ConvertPro, OptinMonster, NotificationX, etc, the page loads with an ugly white space under the notification bar before the sticky header appears.   It's like the code creates an extra white space for the notification bar and pushes ALL of it down, before rendering Elementor's sticky header elements.

The issue only occurs when the nav and menu bar are set to 'sticky' in Elementor.  If 'sticky' is not set, then the notification bar appears properly and pushes down the elements without the ugly white space.

You can see it happening now at https://posterprintshop.com

Is this an issue in Elementor?  Any ideas how to fix or adjust the CSS?